How should we describe the "untagged" tag in the wiki summary?
I happened to stumble over the "untagged" tag. It is only used by a single question, which indeed introduces the problem of finding a better tag than "untagged". 
Yet, I'm not sure if that tag is indeed the best solution. Does an "untagged" tag actually make sense? If yes, what would be the best way to describe that tag in the wiki summary?

The untagged tag is used automatically by the engine when a migrated question arrives without tags (because none of its original tags are existing here) or when a question ends up without tags due to automatic tag cleanup (tags which for half a year have only one question are deleted).
When you find such a question, please find some useful tags for it (optimally already existing tags, or tags which you at the same time also can give to other questions) and replace untagged by them.
(I have untagged as my single favorite tag to see such questions highlighted.)
Something based on this information could be used as the tag wiki text, too, feel free to propose a nice text.

Aha. That's great information - I just learned something new. Thanks for taking the time. Much appreciated indeed! I'll see what I'm able to come up with. Yet, your description actually looks pretty good too. ;)

Is it actually possible to give a description/wiki to the untagged tag? It doesn't appear in the tag list and I can't seem to edit it. Or is this a special moderators-only tag?

@Thomas It doesn't appear in the tag list and you can't write a tag wiki for it because it doesn't exist. Tags that are present on no question are removed by a nightly job. If it comes back there's no point in writing a tag wiki for it since that tag wiki would be removed with the tag (and wouldn't come back if another tag with the same name was created).
